# Better text area input

Tags: html, input, textbox, logic

When you make a question on Stack Overflow, you get a text area box with options like "bold", "italic", "add hyperlink" and everything. I want to do the same thing... But how would I do this? Is there any examples of this? I'm sure there is something on the internet for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try googling for wysiwyg plugins, like CLEditor jQuery plugin http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

Answer (score 5):

At the very coarse high-level view, those fancy online editors are just a div that's had its [`contentEditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute set to true. the button bars, menus, etc... are just fluffy extras.

Comment: I've read through a dozen different SO questions along this line of thought, and this is the first mention of `contentEditable` that I came across.  Exactly what I was looking for, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should use tinymce, etc.

But specifically on Stackoverflow, they use Markdown and a simple textarea. The few buttons here just insert simple ascii-text for the markdown symbols into the textarea

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at W(hat) Y(ou) S(ee) I(s) W(hat) Y(ou) G(et) Editors. Examples: [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) , [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: This is different. Very, very different.

Comment: with TinyMCE is it possible to only allow a couple buttons? Like only allow users to do BOLD, Italic, and font size?

Comment: Altough not needed any more: Yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also study the source for this web page. I recommend the **Firebug** plugin for Firefox. It makes it much easier to navigate the source of a web page.

Simply right-click on an html element, like a text-area, or a button, and click "Inspect element". It goes straight to the source.

I haven't delved my hand in web design for a little while, but there's clearly a lot of CSS and maybe JavaScript going on, both of which (as they are client-side) you can see in the source.